# Xdebug on production server for single account

Tags: php, centos, lamp, xdebug

I have a situation where i have a development site on the same server as a number of production sites, not ideal i know. I would like to use xdebug for the development site but i'm concerned it will create unnecessary overhead on the production sites. Assuming i disabled the error handler, tracing and profiling for all the production sites and just enabled these for the dev site then is this likely to cause any issues?

CentOS 5 server running PHP 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the Xdebug account on [twitter](https://twitter.com/xdebug/status/50262398933798912)

> There is still a bit (of overhead), about 10%.
>   Xdebug 2.2 (currently SVN-only) have
>   some improvements for this with
>   xdebug.coverage_enable=0